# Rust Wasm constructor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: typescript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I'm following the simple example as in [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/constructor.html) to export a rust struct to a React TypeScript application :

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Foo {
    contents: u32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Foo {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Foo {
        Foo { contents: 0 }
    }

    pub fn get_contents(&self) -> u32 {
        self.contents
    }
}
```

Then I add to `App.tsx` the following

```
function App() {
let f = new Foo();
[...]
```

However when I run the react app I get :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo_new')

The struct is exported in `module.js` as:

```
export class Foo {

    static __wrap(ptr) {
        const obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
        obj.ptr = ptr;

        return obj;
    }

    __destroy_into_raw() {
        const ptr = this.ptr;
        this.ptr = 0;

        return ptr;
    }

    free() {
        const ptr = this.__destroy_into_raw();
        wasm.__wbg_foo_free(ptr);
    }
    /**
    */
    constructor() {
        const ret = wasm.foo_new(); <--- fails here
        return Foo.__wrap(ret);
    }
    /**
    * @returns {number}
    */
    get_contents() {
        const ret = wasm.__wbg_get_player_id(this.ptr);
        return ret >>> 0;
    }
}
```

and in `module.d.ts` as:

```
export class Foo {
  free(): void;
/**
*/
  constructor();
/**
* @returns {number}
*/
  get_contents(): number;
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: wasm module loading is ALWAYS async. It’s not workaround-able. You have to somehow wait till it get loaded.

Comment: Look into `module.js` and find the place where `wasm` variable is assigned a value. I’m pretty sure there must be a related promise around that place. Use that promise as a signal of “readiness” to call `new Foo`. In fact search for the word “ready” in the code you’ll probably find something.

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same error as you do. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo_new')` error indicates that your WASM library is not loaded. After reading the .js file generated by the WASM bindgen, I noticed that the `wasm` object needs to be initialized which can be done via the `init` function. Moreover, the `init` function has been exported.

```js
export { initSync }
export default init;
```

Therefore, the solution to your problem is to initialize the `wasm` object through `init` function before using `Foo`.

Let's say the name of the Rust project is `rust_wasm`, I do the following:

1. Import the functions

```
import rust_wasm_init from "rust_wasm";
import {Foo} from "rust_wasm";
```

2. Run the functions

```
async run_wasm_funcion() {
    const path_to_wasm = "https://localhost:3000/static/js/rust_wasm.wasm"; //Remember to update the parameter in CopyPlugin
    await rust_wasm_init(path_to_wasm); //This initializes the wasm object mentioned above
    const foo = new Foo();
    console.log(foo.get_contents());
}
```

Comment: After using Parcel and Webpack, which didn't require this, I wondered why Vite had issues, so thank you for this.